# clamscan not skipping large files and has fmap error

Tags: linux, antivirus

I would expect clamscan to skip files larger than 1k as specified below, but I do not see that the flag max file size makes a difference. Also, a mysterious fmap() error crops up occasionally for a given file, usually a large file, which again, I do not expect to happen at all given the flag. 
The offending file here is "bigfile".

[on CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core) ]

```
$ clamscan --version
ClamAV 0.98.7/21131/Thu Dec  3 12:36:39 2015

$ ls -lash clamscan_investigation
total 3.1G
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 2 padmin users 4.0K Dec  2 16:51 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 7 padmin users 4.0K Dec  3 14:51 ..
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 padmin users  587 Dec  2 14:25 biggest
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 padmin users 2.6K Dec  2 14:27 culprits
1.9G -rw-r--r-- 1 padmin users 1.9G Dec  2 16:34 bigfile
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 padmin users  142 Dec  2 14:08 largest
72K -rw-r--r-- 1 padmin users  71K Dec  2 14:30 out
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root    root  1.5K Dec  2 14:08 s_backups
520K -rw-r--r-- 1 root    root  517K Dec  2 14:15 s_md1
0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     0 Dec  2 14:15 s_md2
1.3G -rw-r--r-- 1 padmin users 1.3G Dec  2 16:32 sss

$ sudo clamscan -r clamscan_investigation
clamscan_investigation/culprits: OK
clamscan_investigation/sss: OK
clamscan_investigation/s_md2: Empty file
clamscan_investigation/out: OK
clamscan_investigation/biggest: OK
clamscan_investigation/largest: OK
clamscan_investigation/s_md1: OK
clamscan_investigation/s_backups: OK
LibClamAV Warning: fmap: map allocation failed
LibClamAV Error: CRITICAL: fmap() failed
clamscan_investigation/bigfile: Can't allocate memory ERROR

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 4135518
Engine version: 0.98.7
Scanned directories: 1
Scanned files: 7
Infected files: 0
Total errors: 1
Data scanned: 1.14 MB
Data read: 3100.86 MB (ratio 0.00:1) 
Time: 9.578 sec (0 m 9 s)

$ sudo clamscan -r clamscan_investigation --max-filesize=1k
clamscan_investigation/culprits: OK
clamscan_investigation/sss: OK
clamscan_investigation/s_md2: Empty file
clamscan_investigation/out: OK
clamscan_investigation/biggest: OK
clamscan_investigation/largest: OK
clamscan_investigation/s_md1: OK
clamscan_investigation/s_backups: OK
LibClamAV Warning: fmap: map allocation failed
LibClamAV Error: CRITICAL: fmap() failed
clamscan_investigation/bigfile: Can't allocate memory ERROR

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 4135518
Engine version: 0.98.7
Scanned directories: 1
Scanned files: 7
Infected files: 0
Total errors: 1
Data scanned: 0.00 MB
Data read: 3100.86 MB (ratio 0.00:1)
Time: 9.027 sec (0 m 9 s)
```